Recuperar data MySQL en Wamp
Se me daño un SSD de un pc de desarrollo, lo que hice fue reemplazar el SSD y volver a instalar el Wamp pero no tenía el respaldo actualizado de las bases de datos, decidí buscar las bases de datos en el SSD dañado y allí estaban en el directorio
bin\mysql\mysql5.7.31\data\
decidí copiar todo el directorio mysql5.7.31\data\ a la nueva ruta bin\mysql\ esperando recuperar las bases de datos, pero no funciono, los modelos aparecían con el nombre, pero las tablas no.
Tables could not be fetched

¿Que debo hacer para recuperar las bases de datos?

Detener todos los servicios de Wamp.
En el directorio original de la nueva instalación bin\mysql\data\, se pegan todos directorios de las bases de datos propias que están en bin\mysql\mysql5.7.31\data\ no las del systema, además, pegue el archivo ibdata1
Inicie todos los servicios de Wamp.
